# Where can I get my biometrics done for my Canadian visa application in Miami?

Tags: visas, canada, miami

I'm applying for a Canadian visa. I'm Sri Lankan but currently studying in the states on an m1 visa and I live in Miami. Does anybody know where I can get biometrics done or will I have to fly to New York or Los Angeles?

And since I'm being sponsored by my dad here, should I also say he'll be sponsoring my trip or will showing my bank account and things here be enough? And if I'm saying he's sponsoring me what proof will I need and how current will they need to be?

Comment: This should be two questions--one on where to get the biometrics done, and one on sponsorship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get Biometrics for a Canadian Visa done at any USCIS Application Support Center (ASC).  The list of [ASC's in Florida is on the USCIS website](https://egov.uscis.gov/crisgwi/go?action=offices.summary&OfficeLocator.office_type=ASC&OfficeLocator.statecode=FL).

You can find the instructions for attending an ASC on the [Canadian Government website](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/biometrics2.asp) - scroll down to the section entitled "If applying from within the United States"