# Biometric question for TVR for Canadian Visa application

Tags: visas, usa, canada, applications

There is a question related to  [Where can I get my biometrics done for my Canadian visa application in Miami?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26176/where-can-i-get-my-biometrics-done-for-my-canadian-visa-application-in-miami/58615#58615). I just want to be 100% sure that I'm doing things right.

Reading in the website the following of the Government of Canada, they have the following guidelines:

> **If applying from within the United States**
>
> -If you need to give your biometrics, you can no longer mail in your application to a Canadian visa office in the U.S. You must submit your
>   biometrics to the VAC in New York or California, or apply online. 
>   -CIC will send you a biometric instruction letter by mail or by email through your MyCIC account when we receive your online application.
>   Read this letter, print a copy and bring it, along with your passport
>   or other travel document, **to an Application Support Centre (ASC) to
>   give your biometrics.** 
>   -**Go to a VAC in New York or Californa, or go to an ASC between the hours of 11:00 a.m. and 2:00 p.m. You do not need to make an
>   appointment.** 
>   -Go to the ASC that is closest to the zip code you gave on your application. 
>   -**Your $85 CAD biometric fee covers the cost of having your biometrics taken at the ASC. ASCs do not accept immigrant or temporary
>   resident applications and cannot provide information or application
>   handling services.** 
>   -Find your closest ASC.

However, if I go the to my closest ASC, which is located in Wisconsin, they say the following:

> Case Services The only after filing service that is provided by an ASC
>   is fingerprinting. Fingerprinting services are by appointment only and
>   are related to an application for an immigration benefit. You will be
>   notified about an ASC appointment by mail. You should follow the
>   instructions on the appointment notice to reschedule the appointment.

**Do I have to go to a VAC? Can I get my biometrics taken in an ASC? 
- I have to make an appointment, and if that's the case. How do I do it?**

Comment: The biometrics needed are fingerprints and a picture so the WI ASC should do just fine, why do you think you need to go to a VAC ?